# Using "and" in Bash while loop

Tags: linux, bash

Okay, essentially this is what the script looks like:

```
echo -n "Guess my number: "
read guess

while [ $guess != 5 ]; do
echo Your answer is $guess. This is incorrect. Please try again.
echo -n "What is your guess? "
read guess
done

echo "That's correct! The answer was $guess!"
```

What I want to change is this line:

```
while [ $guess != 5 ]; do
```

To something like this:

```
while [ $guess != 5 and $guess != 10 ]; do
```

In Java I know "and" is " && " but that doesn't seem to work here. Am I going about this the right way using a while loop?

Comment: The question title was originally "or" instead of "and". Of course, per de Morgan's law, it's logically all the same whether you phrase the requirement as "I want 5 or 10" or with a double negation "I don't want an answer which isn't 5 and isn't 10".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The `[]` operator in bash is syntactic sugar for a call to `test`, which is documented in `man test`. "or" is expressed by an infix `-o`, but you need an "and":

```
while [ $guess != 5 -a $guess != 10 ]; do
```

Comment: yep, my mistake "and" was the one I should be using. That'll explain why "-o" didn't work when I tried it earlier; I just thought it was applicable only to if statements when it gave me an error. Thank you very much for your prompt response!

Comment: Note: this is not POSIX and so not portable.

Answer (score 61):

There are 2 correct and portable ways to achieve what you want.
Good old `shell` syntax:

```
while [ "$guess" != 5 ] && [ "$guess" != 10 ]; do
```

And `bash` syntax (as you specify):

```
while [[ "$guess" != 5 && "$guess" != 10 ]]; do
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to let me know, I noticed now I wasn't bracketing off the two statements and that was why it wasn't working.

Answer (score 2):

The portable and robust way is to use a `case` statement instead.  If you are not used to it, it might take a few looks just to wrap your head around the syntax.

```
while true; do
    case $guess in 5 | 10) break ;; esac
    echo Your answer is $guess. This is incorrect. Please try again.
    echo -n "What is your guess? "
    read guess  # not $guess
done
```

I used `while true` but you could in fact use the `case` statement there directly.  It gets hairy to read and maintain, though.

```
while case $guess in 5 | 10) false;; *) true;; esac; do ...
```